# M2 Custom Product Placeholder Image not showing on Stage or Prod server at Product Detail Level

Tags: magento2, admin, placeholder

I added an image to show images that aren't available (a placeholder) through the M2 admin. It is showing at the category level but not at the product level.

It works on my local machine  which is weird but on the staging and prod server it still shows the default Magento placeholder:

[image]

What's going on?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!!!

Answer (score -2):

```
media/catalog/product/placeholder/default
```

Create placeholder/default directory in `media/product` folder and then upload placeholder image(with name `image.jpg`) in this folder.

It works for me, hope also work for you.